# How To Find Files Based On their Permissions In Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I have more then 50 files and I need to find the ones that have:

- No r permission for group
- No w permission for group
- No x permission for group
- w or r permission for others

I tried the command

```
find <directory> -perm /102
```

but its showing the files with w and r permission for group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-perm /102` will simply match files which have *any* of those bits set, as described in the manpage.

To achieve what you want, you need two `-perm` predicates; one that excludes your "no" permissions, and one which includes your "yes" permission:

```
find ... \! -perm /070 -perm /006
```